# Django: How do I use the result from one function in a model to use in another model's function?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to use the total_pages in the Book model to find the remaining_pages. I don't know what to put for **?**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_page = models.IntegerField()
    end_page = models.IntegerField()

    def total_pages(self):
        total_pages = self.start_page-self.end_page
        return total_pages

class Tracker(models.Model):
    dateRead = models.DateTimeField('entry date')
    bookmark = models.IntField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def remainingPages(self):
        remaining_pages = ? - self.bookmark
        return remaining_pages
```

Comment: `self.book.total_pages()`

Comment: ^this! Thanks Boris, I'm still learning Django :p